# Issue with layouts for Samsung galaxy note and Samsung galaxy grand duos

Tags: android, layout, screen, resolutions

I have created an application with different layout folders. When I tested the application I found that both Samsung galaxy Note2 and Samsung Galaxy Grand Duos is taking the same layout folder 'layout-sw320dp-long-port'. What is the issue here? Can anybody tell that what is the correct layout for both phones?

Thanks in advance

Sundeep.S.

Answer (score 0):

I never believe that Note2 has same screen resolution as Grand Duos.

Check this links :

[ScreenSupports](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

[Review Samsung Note2](http://www.techradar.com/reviews/phones/mobile-phones/samsung-galaxy-note-2-1093688/specification)

[Review Samsung Galaxy Grand Duos](http://www.techradar.com/reviews/phones/mobile-phones/samsung-galaxy-grand-1134387/specification)

As you see this phones has different screen resolution.